# regex to replace zero's

Tags: regex

I would like some help with the following regexes.

```
00  should be replaced by Null
01  should be left as it is
0   should be replaced by Null
```

if there is a single 0 or two 0's then they should be replaced by Null's

My try is

```
select regexp_replace('0','^0',NULL) from dual
```

but my code will not work correct for 01

Got this to work using

```
select regexp_replace('01','^0(0)?',NULL) from dual
```

Comment: You cannot do that with a regexp_replace statement since it will replace with a string value. You need case.

Comment: Your updated answer/solution will only replace the first one or two zeros. If you do only ever want to replace strings of a maximum of two zero's, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work?

```
select regexp_replace('0','^0+$',NULL) from dual
```

I believe this should replace a string which just contains 0's with NULL.

I got the oracle regex syntax from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/ap_posix001.htm#i690819).

If you do only wish to update strings of one or two zeros, use the following:

```
select regexp_replace('0','^0{1,2}$',NULL) from dual
```

or

```
select regexp_replace('0','^0(0)?$',NULL) from dual
```

Comment: I will accept your answer can you please let me know sir what your regex means in english.stackoverflow demands that i wait for 10mins before i accept your answer

Comment: `^` means the start of the string, `0+` means 1 or more zeros, and `$` means the end of the string. So this will replace any string consisting of just 1 or more zeros.

Comment: Brilliant Sir i appreciate very much

Comment: Hi Can you please explain this in your regex {1,2}

Comment: `{1,2}` is a range it says the previous selector can occur a minimum of 1 and a maximum of 2 times.